# $_GET vs get_query_var()

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, query-variable

Is there is any advantage of using the `get_query_var()` over `$_GET()`?

I have tried like this

```
myurl?posts_per_page=2
```

and the results are totally different

```
echo $_GET['posts_per_page'] // output is 2
echo get_query_var('posts_per_page') //output is 10
```

I have not added 'posts_per_page' to query var list using action so where does this 10 is coming up from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_query_var()` gets variables from the main instance of `WP_Query`. It's the equivalent of running

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->get( 'posts_per_page' );
```

It is not *directly* related to `$_GET` in any way. However, WordPress has a list of 'public' query variables that will be applied to the main query if they are passed as URL parameters. This is what the [`query_vars`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/) is filtering. You can see the list [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/), as the `$public_query_vars` property of the `WP` class.

So when you run `get_query_var('posts_per_page')` you are getting the `posts_per_page` property of the main query. This will typically be the value from *Settings > Reading*. Passing `?posts_per_page=2` is not setting this value because `posts_per_page` is not a *public* query variable.